# Panel with vertical buttons

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to create menus on an html page with bootstrap where each menu has a number of buttons which one can choose. I want to show them vertically. I managed to find this code which outputs the buttons horizontally. Is there anyway I can make the buttons underneath each other?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
  <h4 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">Panel header</h4>
  <div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Lock</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Delete</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Move</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this, https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_button_groups.asp

Comment: Add `d-block` class to your `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `<div class="btn-group pull-right">` to `<div class="btn-group-vertical pull-right">`

Using the `btn-group-vertical` class you can make the button display below each other.